# Getting "Runtime error: code size to deposit exceeds maximum code size" when deploying contract with web3 on ganache

Tags: nft, ganache, mocha

I'm new to blockchain. I'm trying to deploying a contract through web3 on [ganache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache) (the npm version) for testing purpose with mocha.

During the deployment attempt, ganache returns with the following error:

"Runtime error: code size to deposit exceeds maximum code size"

If i deploy the same smart contract with truffle on ganache (the application), everything goes fine. My implementation of the contract uses some openzeppelin library. Here is my code:

**Test script**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache');

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { abi, bytecode } = require('../build/contracts/LotteryNftAward.json');

let lottery;
let accounts;

const TOTAL_SUPPLY = 5;

beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    lottery = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: [TOTAL_SUPPLY]})
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000 });    
});

describe('Lottery Contract', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        assert.ok(lottery.options.address);
    });
});
```

**Contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";


contract LotteryNftAward is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    struct Player {
        address playerAddress;
        bool hasWon;
    }

    event Subscription(address newPlayer, uint256 totalSubscription);
    
    uint256 immutable TOTAL_SUPPLY;

    Player[] private players;

    mapping(address => bool) private claimTracker;

    constructor(uint256 totalSupply) ERC721("LotteryNftAward", "LNA") {
        TOTAL_SUPPLY = totalSupply;
    }

    function getPlayersAddresses() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        address[] memory playersAddresses = new address[](players.length);
        
        for(uint i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            playersAddresses[i] = players[i].playerAddress;
        }

        return playersAddresses;
    }

    function subscribe(address player) external onlyOwner {
        Player memory newPlayer = Player({
            playerAddress: player,
            hasWon: false
        });
        
        players.push(newPlayer);

        emit Subscription(player, players.length);
        
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, getPlayersAddresses())));
    }

    function pickWinners() external view onlyOwner returns (address [] memory) {
        address[] memory winners;
        if(players.length <= TOTAL_SUPPLY) {
            winners = new address[](players.length);
            for(uint i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                Player memory winner = players[i];
                winner.hasWon = true;
                winners[i] = winner.playerAddress;
            }
        } else {
            winners = new address[](TOTAL_SUPPLY);
            for(uint i = 0; i < TOTAL_SUPPLY; i++) {
                uint winnerIndex = random() % players.length;
                Player memory candidatePlayer = players[winnerIndex];
                
                if(candidatePlayer.hasWon){
                    continue;
                }
                
                candidatePlayer.hasWon = true;
                winners[i] = candidatePlayer.playerAddress;
            }
        }

        return winners;
    }

    function claim() external {
        uint256 currentTokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();

        require(currentTokenId < TOTAL_SUPPLY, "No more tokens to claim");
        require(!claimTracker[msg.sender], "This address has already claimed");
        
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();

        claimTracker[msg.sender] = true;
        
        _safeMint(msg.sender, _tokenIdCounter.current());
        
    }

}
```

Comment: compile after enabling optimization 200 and send more gas. those contracts are big , gas: 1000000 is not enough

Comment: with 10000000 and optimization 200 it works, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Majd TL suggested in his answer, with 10000000 gas and optimization 200 it worked

Comment: you don't need 10000000, just deploy it once on a test net using remix and check how much it really consumes